# Action sheet in an UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiactionsheet, screen-rotation

I have a full screen UIScrollView to display my image. And the scroll view recognize long press gesture. After long pressing on the scrollview, an action sheet shows up. If i add the action sheet to the window, it will not rotate while I am rotating the screen. If i add it to the scroll view, it rotates but not that good when the scroll view has been zoomed or scrolled. Is it possible to rotate the action sheet well regardless of the scrolling and zooming of the scroll view?

ps. the scroll view is directly add to the window by "self.view = myScrollView;"

Comment: Can't you just add the ActionSheet to the view in which the scrollview resides?

Comment: the scroll view reside in the window.

Comment: No `UIViewController` which hold all the logic? You should just use `MVC` and place the scrollview in view which is controlled by an `UIViewController`.

Comment: Of course I have a UIViewController. I think is the window holding the scroll view

Comment: You should just add the `UIScrollView` to the `UIView` of the `UIViewController`. Then you can add the ActionSheet to the view of the viewcontroller.

Comment: Yes, I am trying this method now, a little problem when I rotate the screen after zooming the image. Maybe it's something about autosizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the scrollView to the rootviewcontroller or the parent view on which scrollview resides would be better and solve you problem.

Comment: the scroll view reside in the window.

Comment: Add the UIActionSheet and the scrollview over another viewcontroller and add the parent viewcontroller over the window and not thw actionsheet directly to the window